# Create an array from text input when submitted only using vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I'm new to Stack Overflow and honestly coding in general (graphics is my background).  I'm still learning and my verbiage may be off, I apologize in advance.

I am attempting to write an app in vanilla js (or pure js) and would like for a user to enter in names and those names then be converted to an array that I can later manipulate into an unordered list.

This is my HTML:

```
<h2>Create Your Team</h2>
<input type="text" class="player" name="Player" data-player-type="player" value="enter name" />
<input type="text" class="player" name="Player" data-player-type="player" value="enter name1"/>
<input type="text" class="player" name="Player" data-player-type="player" value="enter name2"/>
<input type="text" class="player" name="Player" data-player-type="player" value="enter name3"/><br />
<input type="button" id="go" value="Go >>" onclick="createJSONObject()" />
```

And this is my JS thus so far

```
  const inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".player")
  const values = Array.from(inputs).map(input => input.value)
  console.log('values', values);
```

This works for static entry but would I'd like to do is now take the user's value and make that the array upon submit of a button (or enter).

Could I please get some help on that?  Thank you.

Here is the JSFiddle as well.
[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/sthig/yoadc45c/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an event listener on your button:

```
document.getElementById("go").addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Your JS code
});
```

By the way, that's pure JS's way.

Comment: ok, you're amazing.  Thank you for that extremely quick answer! And it worked flawlessly! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Updated your fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/yoadc45c/1/

This code:

```
<input type="button" id="go" value="Go >>" onclick="createJSONObject()" />
```

This can't work in a fiddle because a) createJSONObject wasn't defined and b) calling your js function on the html section from the js section doesn't work. I'm pretty sure js fiddle doesn't allow that.

Just use Eduardo's example. My fiddle is an updated version of your code, plus his event listener.

Comment: yes I found out about that when I ran the code.  Thank you for your help!